# Array.filter not working as expected, I am getting Null Array in the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arrow-functions

```
const normArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];           //array

const mapArray = normArray.map((num)=>{ 
  return num * 5;
})                                           //mapping

const filterArray = mapArray.filter((num)=>{ 
  num > 5;
})                                           //filtering


console.log(mapArray);
console.log(filterArray);
```

Output is = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] & [ ] , why null filtered Array?
Peace & Blessings be upon you :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a boolean inside the function parameter. It should be:

```
const filterArray = mapArray.filter((num)=>{ 
  return num > 5;
});
```

Comment: sorry it was not =, it was num>5 there. edited

Comment: ok, I've edited the answer. Add the return so the filter will return [10, 15, 20, 25]